# How to handle application created images?

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I would like to upload files to server, and my application can run without network, and because of this, I have to save the files, that the user picks and upload later.

I don't want to save thease pictures into database, bacause as I read it is a bad practice, so I decided to I create a copy of the file, and after that I save the copied file uri string to database.

It is working good, but if I close the application, and opened it again, the uri is not valid, or probably I don't have permission anymore to read or write.

So how can I perform this behavior?
And why lose the application the uri permission, if it is created by himself?

I tired to get persistable uri permission, but I get an java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found exception.

```
File copy

val copyOfFile = createFile(
                application.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                fileMetaData.extension,
                fileMetaData.fileName,
                true
            )

            val outPut = FileOutputStream(copyOfFile)
            inputStream.copyTo(outPut)

            val newFileUri =
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(application, application.packageName, copyOfFile)


            application.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                newFileUri,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            )
            return CopyFileResult(
                copyOfFile.name,
                fileMetaData.extension,
                newFileUri.toString()
            )

Open uri
val uri = Uri.parse(document.uriString!!)
val bitmap = documentManagerService.getBitmapFromUri(uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.

I save the filePath to database instead of uri string, and later the file is exists and I can use.